# Insert Data into Database

Tags: plugin-development, database

I´m new in developing Plugins for wordpress.

I need a formular where all viewers of the website can fill in data and send it. The **send it**-button should save it to database.

So I think the way is to define the shortcut and the Formular in the plugin like this:

```
function formular() {
  return 'This is html of Formular';
}
add_shortcode("formular", "formular");
```

But then I don´t now how to define the Formular with a button to save the data into database. A Database-Table where the data should be saved is already added.

Somebody has got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that with sending the form to the script `admin-post.php` with that in the form :

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo admin_url("admin-post.php");?>?action=myPlugin__save_datas">
```

after that, you use this hook for the PHP treatment

```
add_action("admin_init", function () {

    if (    !isset($_POST["action"])
        ||  ("myPlugin__save_datas" !== $_POST["action"])
    ) {
        return;
    }


    // save datas
    // ...


    // redirection

    $url = home_url("/");

    wp_redirect($url);
    exit();

});
```

If you want just send form on connected or unconnected user, you have respectively the actions `admin_post_myPlugin__save_datas` and `admin_post_nopriv_myPlugin__save_datas`

Comment: Wouldn't `admin_init` never get triggered for visitors that aren't logged in? Any particular reason for using admin-post.php instead of the regular ajax?

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but there is an error. The error message is "syntax error, unexpected 'function'"